# hover effect creates flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am trying to display options on an image on hover but when I hover the displayed options keeps flickering

```
      $('a').hover(function(event) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var top = $(this).next().css("bottom");

            $(this).next().css("display", "block");
            $(this).next().next().css({ 'top': '30px', 'display': 'block' });

    },function() {
            $(this).next().hide();
            $(this).next().next().hide();

    });

});
$('.SelectionAnimate').hover(function() { $(this).css("display", "block"); $(this).next().show(); });
```

the listview code

```
           <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="float: left; position: relative; margin: 10px;" >
                <div>
                    <a class="real" href='<%#"/ProfileTenModified/UserProfile/PhotoCross.aspx?in="+ Eval("Full_Image_Name") +"&mi=" + Eval("User_Id") +"&fd="+ Eval("Album")%>'>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"/ProfileTenModified/setP/"+ Eval("Slide_Thumb_Name") +".JPEG" %>'
                            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="172px" Height="172px" />
                    </a>
                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="SelectionAnimate" ID="Selection" runat="server" Text="Set as Display"
                        OnCommand="ListViewThums_Selection_Command" CommandName="selection"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="SelectionAnimate" ID="Deletion" runat="server" Text="Remove"
                        OnCommand="ListViewThumbs_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldImageId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

I used both the `mouseenter` and `hover` both create the same effect. is there away to solve this

Comment: why the javascript? A simple hover should be easy with just css...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You apply `.hover()` on the `a` only. So when you hover the `a`, the image appear hover your `a` wich mean you are not hover the `a` anymore. That will fire the second callback of `.hover()` and the image will disappear. Then again you are hover the `a` and it repeat infinitly.

To solve that, you just have to bind the `.hover()` on the parent container or on both elements.

Comment: I added the class real but did not use it.. I think I should include .real ??

Comment: No, that wouldn't solve you problem since `.real` is the `a`. But you can try `$('.real').parent().hover(your code)`

Comment: Because it is the siblings of the `a` who are being placed hover. Applying `.hover()` on the parent of the `a` will, in theory, stop the flickering. It's kinda hard to help without a live example...

Comment: Actually, binding the `.hover()` on parent will cause error since the `this` will not be the same as before...

Comment: Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4LzaU/1/. Since it's light weight, you don't see it happen (it is too fast) but you can see the cursor being crazy. From what i understand, it's your problem. But if you apply it on the parent, it will stop flickering : http://jsfiddle.net/4LzaU/2/

Answer (score 1):

I once got similar problem as you have got.
So, to solve this problem i used mouseenter and mouseleave event.

```
$(selector).on('mouseenter', function(){
  //perform what you want whe mouse is on your selector
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  //your code on when mouse leaves the selector
});
```

Comment: if I use `$(selector).parent().on('mouseenter', function(){});` will this be alright

Comment: No this wont work, but if you say that $('a').hover gives you required result and it flickers, than $('a').on('mouseenter' should work. If still there is a problem than put the entire thing in a div, set a class to div and on mouseenter event on that class